# The recorded sound from microphone is very fast

Tags: sound, microphone, audio-recording, recordmydesktop, kazam

I am using Kazam to record videos. But when I see the video I notice that the recorded sound is much faster than I speak (like 10s turned back to 2s). I tried RecordMyDesktop software but still the same problem. Sometimes it works normally but not the same sound that was fast.

I tried to change fps from 15 to 5 or from 15 to 30 but still the same. I am recording with the microphone of a webcam (see the image below). Of course I am not using "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo". All the details are in the screenshots below.

Sorry for my bad english.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

[image: Kazam version]

[image: Input devices settings]

This is the ouput of `pacmd list-sources`

```
3 source(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: IDLE
suspend cause: 
priority: 1950
volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 0.00 ms
max rewind: 64 KiB
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 371.52 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
monitor_of: 0
card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
module: 6
properties:
    device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
    device.class = "monitor"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel at 0xe04c0000 irq 24"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "27d8"
    device.product.name = "NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9959
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 17106 /  26% / -35.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 130.77 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 371.52 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC260 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC260 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel at 0xe04c0000 irq 24"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "27d8"
        device.product.name = "NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC260"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0260,103c3011,00100400"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:

active port: <analog-input-mic>
index: 2
name: <alsa_input.usb-046d_0825_20169E00-02.analog-mono>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
state: IDLE
suspend cause: 
priority: 9049
volume: mono: 85979 / 131% / 7.07 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 20724 /  32% / -30.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 69.22 ms
max rewind: 0 KiB
sample spec: s16le 1ch 48000Hz
channel map: mono
             Mono
used by: 0
linked by: 0
configured latency: 2000.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
card: 1 <alsa_card.usb-046d_0825_20169E00-02>
module: 7
properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = "USB Audio"
    alsa.id = "USB Audio"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "0"
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x825"
    alsa.long_card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x825 at usb-0000:00:1d.7-6, high speed"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:6:1.2"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.2/sound/card1"
    udev.id = "usb-046d_0825_20169E00-02"
    device.bus = "usb"
    device.vendor.id = "046d"
    device.vendor.name = "Logitech, Inc."
    device.product.id = "0825"
    device.product.name = "Webcam C270"
    device.serial = "046d_0825_20169E00"
    device.form_factor = "webcam"
    device.string = "hw:1"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "192000"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "96000"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "analog-mono"
    device.profile.description = "Analog Mono"
    device.description = "Webcam C270 Analog Mono"
    alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
    alsa.components = "USB046d:0825"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
ports:
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
active port: <analog-input-mic>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *sound of my microphone is very fast*? Is it high pitched? Is it playing faster than you speak (e.g. 10s played back in 5s)?

Comment: Yeah It's playing faster than I speak ( 10s played back in  2s )

Comment: Do you know anything about the sample rate of the audio device? Can you [edit] your post with the output of `pacmd list-sources`? This will tell us the capabilities of your audio inputs. I am guessing a sample rate missmatch, but this is purely a guess.

Comment: Can you also try a recording with "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo", just to verify if this is OK, or if it has a problem too? And are you able to upload a recording somewhere? It does not have to be your voice, but play for instance some [identifiable audio from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:The_Star-Spangled_Banner_-_U.S._Army_1st_Armored_Division_Band.ogg) on your phone, and record it.

Comment: About "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" It's working correctly now.

Comment: And I edited the post